# mco ping not responding for one node

Tags: puppet, rhel6, mcollective

We have configured 12 servers  with `Puppet/MCollective` . All the servers are rspodning to `mco ping` .  But we had a patch update for OS and after that one of the node is not responding.

```
        $ sudo tail -f mcollective.log
           I, [2016-11-28T17:47:53.493341 #25669]  INFO -- : activemq.rb:129:in `on_connectfail' TCP Connection to stomp+ssl://mcollective@jw-node1-x1:61614 failed on attempt 4620
       I, [2016-11-28T17:48:23.495747 #25669]  INFO -- : activemq.rb:139:in `on_ssl_connecting' Establishing SSL session with stomp+ssl://mcollective@node1-x1:61614
       E, [2016-11-28T17:48:23.635431 #25669] ERROR -- : activemq.rb:149:in `on_ssl_connectfail' SSL session creation with stomp+ssl://mcollective@node1-x1:61614 failed: hostname "node1-x1" does not match the server certificate
```

Puppet version is as follows:

```
    $ /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet --version
      4.5.2
```

I have compared they keys and cerrtifactes which has been exchanged between nodes, but they are same in terms of permission , size and contents of key file.

Please suggest what went wrong after reboot.